# Auto populate recipients in DocuSign Envelope using custom Lightning button

Tags: button, docusign

We have a standard object `Opportunity` and we have DocuSign linked to it. I need to customize a custom button so that it auto populates the DocuSign Envelope's Signer 2 using the Email address of contact information.

a. Lookup field: Opportunity.Program_of_Sale_Contact__c
d. Field name in Contact is Email

```
{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [
SourceID = Opportunity.Id,
CCRM='Signer 1~District Manager;Signer 2~Contact;Signer 3~Regional Manager;Signer 4~Accounts Payable',
CCTM='Signer 1~Signer;Signer 2~Signer;Signer 3~CarbonCopy;Signer 4~CarbonCopy',
LA = '0',
CRL='Email~' + User.Email + ';FirstName~' + User.FirstName + ';LastName~' + User.LastName + ';Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1,Email~;FirstName~;LastName~;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,Email~;'+Opportunity.Program_of_Sale_Contact__c+';Role~Signer 3;RoutingOrder~3,LoadDefaultContacts~0',DST = 'e9034391-53ee-4e25-9433-844270d82873'
]
 
)}
```

I updated code of button for Signer 2 which should goes to "point of Sale Contact" and Email is the field name which stores Email Address. But didn’t work as expected. Above is the code.

Answer (score 1):

First off, a note. The DocuSign For Salesforce (namespace = `dsfs`) package is no longer listed on the AppExchange. It is deprecated, meaning it gets security updates but no feature development. Summer '22 retired some APIs/features that DSFS < v6.4 relied on. You should consider just outright replacing the old DSFS package for the currently supported DocuSign Apps Launcher (namespace = `dfsle`).

When you have long strings like this, it is often helpful to break them down into smaller strings. Even if you can only do that while you're developing the thing (I don't know how well `URLFOR()` can tolerate newlines), it'll help you avoid mistakes.

Taking a look back at some old code of mine, DocuSign's format for the CRL looks like this:

- `Name~Value` pairs
- each pair is separated by a semicolon (`;`)
- each collection of name-value pairs separated by a comma (`,`)

So with that knowledge, let's break down your CRL string

```
CRL=  
'Email~' + User.Email + ';FirstName~' + User.FirstName + ';LastName~' + User.LastName + ';Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1,
Email~;FirstName~;LastName~;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,
Email~;'+Opportunity.Program_of_Sale_Contact__c+';Role~Signer 3;RoutingOrder~3,
LoadDefaultContacts~0'
```

This should make it pretty clear where you made the mistakes. Assuming `Opportunity.Program_of_Sale_Contact__c` is a field containing an Email address...

- You added it for the third signer instead of the second
- You terminated the `Email` name-value pair prior to adding the email

What you say you want should look like this instead (when you break each comma-separated group onto a new line)

```
CRL=  
'Email~' + User.Email + ';FirstName~' + User.FirstName + ';LastName~' + User.LastName + ';Role~Signer 1;RoutingOrder~1,
Email~'+Opportunity.Program_of_Sale_Contact__c+';FirstName~;LastName~;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,
Email~;Role~Signer 3;RoutingOrder~3,
LoadDefaultContacts~0'
```

Comment: thanks @derek F . Do you know how to add Email field of Lookup object in the CRL. The filed name is Email in lookup object so will it be like (+Opportunity.Program_of_Sale_Contact__c.Email) Is this how it works.                                                                      I am getting below error after updating code "Upsert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Recipient Email: invalid email address: [dsfs__Recipient_Email__c]"

Comment: @HPA When you want to traverse a relationship, you change the `__c` at the end of the relationship field to `__r` (or if it's a standard relationship field like AccountId, just simply drop the "Id" part). Note that this only works when you traverse upwards in a relationship hierarchy (from child to parent). Formulas can't go from parent to child (because there can be multiple children, and there is no guaranteed order nor a way to pick a specific record out of a list in a formula).

Comment: Thanks Derek, I have tried by changing __c to __r (+Opportunity.Program_of_Sale_Contact__r.Email) but it gave error message Field "Opportunity.Program_of_Sale_Contact__r.Email does not exist. Check spelling." This is a Standard Object where Opportunity has a Lookup Field to Contact and Email is the name of field in Contact.

Comment: Hi, I found the issue. It was because of one of signer didn't had email address so was giving error otherwise code worked well. Thanks for your help Derek